# Blazor Component - custom namespace & resx files

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0

An Blazor Application is by default organised like:

```
* Pages
     * Index.razor
     * Index.razor.cs
     * Index.razor.css
* Resources
    * Pages
        * Index.resx
        * Index.alternative-CULTURE.resx
```

So the Index is in the namespace MyApplication.Pages by default.
When `IStringLocalizer<Index>` is injected, the resx file is found cause the namespace + name of the Component and the Path of the resx matches right?

So with an big app and subfolders to manage alot of pages you get many namespaces.
One can get rid of the namespaces with `@namespace MyApplication` in the razor and `namespace MyApplication` in the `razor.cs`.

But if you to so, the resx files are no longer found. Only way i found to fix this, is too move the resx files from `Resources/Pages` directly to `Resources`. Then the namespace + name of the Component and the Path of the resx matches again and the resx file is found again.

But that failes the whole idea of managing you pages into subfolders.

Is there any way to give an Component and custom namespace without breaking the connection to the resx file?

Comment: All my solutions are split into multiple projects.  My Blazor UI components and pages (which are only components with a route attribute) live in a different project and thus different namespace.